# SwiftUI: How to trigger api call to retrieve data source when Search Bar's text is changed

Tags: ios, uikit, swiftui, searchbar

I implement a search bar using UIKit to wrap it in `MovieSearchView`. When a user input some keywords then it will show search result in the following list view.

The data `searchResults` is coming from API call `self.model.getMovieSearchResults()`, but in my code, the api call is never triggered. So I'm wondering where should I put the condition checking `onAppear()` in my case to trigger api call, when the search text is changed in Search Bar?

/ / / Search View

```
import SwiftUI

struct MovieSearchView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = MovieListViewModel()
    @State private var searchText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchBar(text: $searchText)
                .onAppear() {
                    // If searchText has a value, then call api to fetch movies data.
                    if self.searchText.isEmpty == false {
                        self.model.getMovieSearchResults(for: self.searchText)
                    }
                }
                List {
                    ForEach(model.searchResults.filter {
                        self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.title.lowercased().contains(self.searchText.lowercased())
                    }) { movie in
                        Text(movie.title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MovieSearchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieSearchView()
    }
}
```

/ / / Search Bar

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

### Update:

Just realize that I don't need to do the filter again, since API call already return the filtered search result from server. Change the code to remove the filter{}. I also add tap gesture to triggering navigation to movie detail view and call page 2 when you hit the bottom.

More update:

- Clear search result when search text is cleared by the user.
- Show cancel button on Search Bar when the user begin editing, and
  dismiss keyboard when cancel button is pressed.

### Search Bar

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String
    var onTextChanged: (String) -> Void

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

        @Binding var text: String
        var onTextChanged: (String) -> Void

        init(text: Binding<String>, onTextChanged: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
            _text = text
            self.onTextChanged = onTextChanged
        }

        // Show cancel button when the user begins editing the search text
        func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        }

        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
            onTextChanged(text)
        }

        func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            text = ""
            searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
            searchBar.endEditing(true)
            // Send back empty string text to search view, trigger self.model.searchResults.removeAll()
            onTextChanged(text)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text, onTextChanged: onTextChanged)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search TMDB"
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        return searchBar
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

### Search View

```
import SwiftUI

struct MovieSearchView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = MovieListViewModel()
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var selectedId = -1
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var page = 1

    var body: some View {
        List {
            SearchBar(text: $searchText, onTextChanged: searchMovies)

            ForEach(0..<model.searchResults.count, id: \.self) { i in
                MovieListRow(movie: self.model.searchResults[i])
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedId = self.model.searchResults[i].id
                        self.showSheet.toggle()
                    }
                .onAppear() {
                    if i == self.model.searchResults.count - 1 {
                        self.page += 1
                        self.model.getMovieSearchResults(for: self.searchText, page: self.page)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SingleMovieView(movieId: self.selectedId)
        }
    }

    func searchMovies(for searchText: String) {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            self.model.getMovieSearchResults(for: self.searchText, page: self.page)
        } else {
            // remove search result when a user clear keyword.
            self.model.searchResults.removeAll()
        }
    }
}

struct MovieSearchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieSearchView()
    }
}
```

Now what is it looked like in my app. Just one thing left, to dismiss the keyboard when scroll down the list.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a closure. Here I added `onTextChanged: (String) -> Void` to the SearchBar.

## MovieSearchView

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MovieSearchView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = MovieListViewModel()
    @State private var searchText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchBar(text: $searchText, onTextChanged: searchMovies)
                
                List {
                    ForEach(model.searchResults.filter {
                        self.searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.title.lowercased().contains(self.searchText.lowercased())
                    }) { movie in
                        Text(movie.title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func searchMovies(for searchText: String) {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            model.getMovieSearchResults(for: searchText)
        }
    }
}

struct MovieSearchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieSearchView()
    }
}
```

## SearchBar

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var onTextChanged: (String) -> Void
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {
        var onTextChanged: (String) -> Void
        @Binding var text: String
        
        init(text: Binding<String>, onTextChanged: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
            _text = text
            self.onTextChanged = onTextChanged
        }
        
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            text = searchText
            onTextChanged(text)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text, onTextChanged: onTextChanged)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> UISearchBar {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
        searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        return searchBar
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

Comment: I try it and it is working well. For my understand, this solution assign the closure, which includes the api call statement to ```SearchBar```. And inside ```SearchBar```,  it will call back the func defined in MovieSearchView, interesting. So we don't need to call the model in ```SearchBar```, we just send a closure. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, `SearchBar` can be used in other views because it doesn't reference your model to work. It only knows it has to call `onTextChanged` with a `String` parameter.

Comment: thanks for the answer, really help. I update my code in question again since I just realize that I do the filter job twice, return data from api call already contains the filtered result. What a idiot of me:)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use searchBarDelegate method like below :

```
func searchBar(UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextIn: NSRange, replacementText: String) -> Bool
```

With each typing you get a callback from the user and inside this function you can fire the api call to server.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have tried this. But it turns out I couldn't type any word in Search Bar after add this func and call api in it.

Comment: you can add check related to text count.